# How to compare two data sets sampled at different time?

Tags: time-series, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have two time series $X$ and $Y$. These two time series contain features, $x_i \in R^{n \times 1}, i = 1...n_x$ and $y_j \in R^{n \times 1}, j=1,...,n_y$ sampled from two subjects($x_i$ are extracted from subject $A$, and $y_j$ are extracted from subject $B$). These features are extracted using the same method, but at different time indices and from different subjects. 
For example,$X=[x_1, x_2, x_3]$, $Y=[y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4]$, $x_i,y_j\in R^{n \times 1}$ and the sampling time indices for $X$ and $Y$ are $t_x = [10,20,30]$ and $t_y = [12,24,36,48]$ respectively. I would like to calculate distance between $X$ and $Y$. If $n_x = n_y$ and $t_x=t_y$, this is simple. However,  $n_x \neq n_y$ and $t_x\neq t_y$ for my data. Is there any method to solve this problem?

Comment: Methods will depend on what relationships you postulate between $X$ and $Y$, as well as assumptions and models about the evolution of both $X$ and $Y$ over time. Since you have said nothing about any relationship, there's not much anyone could say specifically in response.  Please include within edits to your post any additional information about the meaning of these data, your model, and your assumptions.

Comment: Thank you for the edits, but the post remains really vague. Could you elaborate on what exactly you mean by "compare" and what the objective of the comparison might be? What is the nature of these "features"?  If you cannot be concrete about the details, then you must be specific about your mathematical model. Without one or the other this question just won't be answerable.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with whuber that your question is still vague.  However, I will try to provide a solution.  A common model for time series is the ARIMA model.  Assuming this model is a good fit to your data it would allow for estimation and inference on the mean of the process over time.  It would also allow you to extrapolate estimation and inference on the mean at future time points as well as to construct predict intervals for future observations.  Below is a picture from [this](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/etsug/15.2/etsug_varmax_examples12.htm) SAS documentation webpage on Proc VARMAX.  Another related procedure would be Proc ARIMA.

[image]

You could model both of your time series each with different time indices.  By interpolating the means between time points you could compare the means between the series at common time points.

Let me know if this addresses your question or if you were interested in something else.